# Whats the error in this AJAX jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to `removeClass` and `addClass` on the  jQuery `$.get` `success`. But it doesn't seem to work with `$.get` and works only if i include the entire `$.ajax` which i dont want to do.

The following code works:

```
$(".result").on("click", ".myul li",  function(){
    var mydiv = $(this).data("id");
    var enumgroup = {};
    enumgroup["id"]=mydiv;

         $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'checkenumresult.php',
         context:this,
         data: {id: mydiv},
         success: function (data) {
               $(this).removeClass("forseen0").addClass("forseen1");
         }
      });
 });
```

The following code doesnt work:

```
$(".result").on("click", ".myul li",  function(){
    var mydiv = $(this).data("id");
    var enumgroup = {};
    enumgroup["id"]=mydiv;

    $.get("checkenumresult.php", enumgroup, function(){
    context:this,    //tried without this too.
    success: function(data){
       $(this).removeClass("forseen0").addClass("forseen1");
    }
    });
});
```

Both the codes are working with respect to posting data to the php page. Only the 2nd code is not changing class of the element on `success.` What is wrong with the second code?

Comment: You're passing different data in the requests. Check the console for the specific error this causes on the server. Also in the first request you make a `POST`, so surely `$.post()` would be more appropriate in the second example?

Comment: In your first code you are sending data from post and if you want to send data from post use `$.post` instead of `$.get`

Comment: $.get description: Load data from the server using a HTTP GET request. In your ajax request you are using a post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".result").on("click", ".myul li",  function(){
    var mydiv = $(this).data("id");
    var enumgroup = {};
    enumgroup["id"]=mydiv;    
    $.get("checkenumresult.php", enumgroup, function(data){
       $(mydiv).removeClass("forseen0").addClass("forseen1");        
    });
});
```

the third argument in the above get call is the callback for the response

Comment: Thanks. So the `function(data)` is a callback so only if the `enumgroup` is sent to the php page, only thn the class will be applied, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can post data to server in proper format using [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) like:

```
$(".result").on("click", ".myul li", function() {
  vat $this = $(this);
  var mydiv = $this.data("id");
  var enumgroup = {};
  enumgroup["id"] = mydiv;

  $.post("checkenumresult.php", {id: mydiv}, function(data) {
    $this.removeClass("forseen0").addClass("forseen1");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two points to note:
1 - On your `$.ajax` call you're making a `POST` request, while in the other you're trying to make a `GET` request. You need to check your endpoint if he accepts both `POST` and `GET`;

2 - The success callback of your `$.get` request is the [third argument](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), so your request should be something like:

```
$.get("checkenumresult.php", enumgroup, function(data) {
  $(this).removeClass("forseen0").addClass("forseen1");
});
```

If your endpoint only accepts `POST`, just change `$.get` to `$.post`: 
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

FYK: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html